# On the Verification Problem in 'element-UI' form validate question

Tags: vue.js

main component

```
<el-form :model="form" :rules="rules">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in form.involveUsers" :key="index">
  <el-form-item label="mechanismName" :prop="`involveUsers.${index}.mechanismName`" :rules="rules.mechanismName">
    <InstitutionSelection v-model="item.mechanismName"/>
  </el-form-item>
</el-form>


data(){
  form: {
    involveUsers: [
      { mechanismName: '' }
    ],
    rules: {
      mechanismName: [ { required: true,message: 'mechanismName is required' } ]
    }
}
```

InstitutionSelection  component

```
<el-cascader v-model="selected" :options="mechanism" :props=""{ value: 'id', label: 'name' }"/>
<script>
props: { 
  value: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
  }
},
model: { prop: 'value', event: 'setValue' },
data(){
  mechanism: [],//This is a cascading data
  mechanismService: [], //This is the data returned by the server that has not been converted into a tree shape
  selected: []
},
watch: {
  selected(newValue){
    //Here, only the last level ID will be taken for the selected data; like this [ 098 ]
    //Then find the corresponding data in mechanismService; like this { id: 098, name: 'A-1', pId: 0 }
    //Then update the parent component data
    this.$emit('setValue',[{ id: 098, name: 'A-1', pId: 0 }]);
  }
}
</script>;
```

When I select, the input box will display a verification failure message 'mechanismName is required'

When I change the verification rule to `rules:{ mechanismName: [ {validator: mechanismName} ]`

InstitutionSelection  component

```
data(){
  let mechanismName = (rule, value, callBack) => {
    console.log(value); // '' This is the previous default value; When reselecting, you will receive the last selected value
    // After the second reselection, you will see on the console 'involveUsers.0.mechanismName is not a string'
}
```

But the value I get in main component has always been the currently selected value;

I want him to verify the correct results. Can you help me? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Unable to find the reason, but you can manually verify by listening for data changes through @change, which needs to be done in $nextTick